# Prev answer not working to test if DOM is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this: [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433).

When I put it in my JS and force a scroll, it is not reporting the correct information.

```
function inViewport(e) {

//special bonus for those using jQuery
if (e instanceof jQuery) {
    e = e[0];
}

var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect();

return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
     );
}

$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#8").offset().top
});

var divsVisible = [];
$('div[id]').each(function() {
if (inViewport(this)) {
    divsVisible.push( this.id );
}
});     

debug.log(divsVisible);
```

My HTML file is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/163931/index.html

I would expect the array to have '8' in it. Instead it has '1' in it. Mac/Safari.

Comment: What happens if you call the `inViewport` function **after** the animation? Right now you are calling it **before** the animation is complete.

Comment: How do I call it after? I'm new to jquery and don't quite have it all figured out.

Comment: Pass a complete callback to `.animate` and put your code inside the callback: https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete . Also see https://learn.jquery.com/effects/custom-effects/

Comment: So it doesn't do statements in order then? How do I ensure order? I will try that tomorrow when I'm back in front of computer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `.animate` kicks of an asynchronous process, which is only started *after* the current execution terminates. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop. You ensure order by passing a callback to `.animate`. The callback is executed when the animation finished.

Comment: I tried this code: `$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#8").offset().top,
   complete: function() {
    alert('in');
   }
});` and the alert is not fired.

Comment: That's because you are not using the API correctly. Have a look at the documentation again: https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete. Just pass the function as second argument to `.animate`.

Comment: @FelixKling: thanks! Not sure why my options/properties way wasn't working but I got it firing now. If you know anything about Scrollfire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399378/jquery-plugin-scrollfire-not-firing-properly